# Access parent Model class fields in filter query

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible to access the fields in a parent Model through a filter query?

For example if I have the following Model structure:

```
class Space(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ident = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Airwaves(Space):
    @cached_property
    def stations(self):
        name_substr = self.name
        if " " in name_substr:
            name_substr = name_substr[:name_substr.index(" ")]

        return Station.objects.filter(Q(ident__contains=self.ident) |
                                          Q(name__contains=self.name) |
                                          Q(name__contains=name_substr))

class Radio(models.Model):
    # The fields I would like to access from Airwaves
    ident = models.CharField(max_length=4) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Station(Radio):
    frequency = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

With the existing code I get the error `Cannot resolve keyword 'ident' into field. Choices are: frequency, id`.

How can I access the `ident` and `name` fields for the filter query in `Airwaves`?

Comment: Where is the code that is causing the error?  I don’t see any use of the `ident` field.

Comment: @2ps I apologize. It's a pretty long query, so I shortened it for the sake of the post. I've added the missing information and additional structure above.

Comment: Have you try to run same Station query in shell.

Comment: @swiftsly:  I just pasted your code into a new project and it works without modification.  If there is an error, it isn’t in the posted code.